# Format for thousands number with two decimal places insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have value `1000` and I want it to be with two decimal place. So what I did was I used the number format function.

```
number_format(1000,2);
```

And so my output would be like this `1,000.00`. However, I cannot insert `1,000` value with the , sign into my db table type decimal (6,2). Is there any way that I can insert my `1000` value together with the two decimal place. Or I need to change my table type?

Comment: I guess the column in your database is set to int?

Comment: Insert the unformatted number in your database.... only format numbers when you actually display them

Comment: @MarkBaker Agreed, only store the meaning of the data into the database, not the representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store as `DECIMAL` and format it using `FORMAT`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col DECIMAL(6,2) );

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (10), (67), (1000), (1006.2);

SELECT FORMAT(col, 2) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1a6a/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╗
║  result  ║
╠══════════╣
║ 10.00    ║
║ 67.00    ║
║ 1,000.00 ║
║ 1,006.20 ║
╚══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bcadd()`,

```
$a = bcadd("100","0","2");
echo $a;// output is 100.00
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php) for more reference